# OSX: Why my app needs click on it first to receive keydown event?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I currently developing a small dictionary app under OSX for my own use, I would like to have a feature that when I hit the return key, the focus would go to the nssearchfeild.

So I try to make the app to receive keyDown event using a NSView and NSViewController told by [this tutorial](http://programminghave.blogspot.com/2014/01/key-and-mouse-events-in-nsviewcontroller.html).

But every time I start the app, it wouldn't receive the keyDown event. I have to click on the window once, then hit the keyboard, so that it can receive keyDown event.

What did I do wrong? Can anyone help me out with this problem? I have been stuck in this problem for days, and searching throught Google and API wouldn't help much.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code for AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MyDictViewController.h"

@interface  AppDelegate()
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet MyDictViewController *viewController;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.viewController = [[MyDictViewController alloc]          initWithNibName:@"MyDictViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.viewController.view];
    self.viewController.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;
    [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
}

@end
```

And My ViewController.m

```
#import "MyDictViewController.h"
#import "FileHelper.h"
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>

@interface MyDictViewController ()
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *wordsFilteredTable;

@end

@implementation MyDictViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.IMAGE_FILE = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Document.png"];
        self.wordlist = [FileHelper readLines];
        self.filterWordlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    [self.view becomeFirstResponder];
}

-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent*)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"Caught key event");
}

-(void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    unsigned short keycode = [theEvent keyCode];

    switch (keycode)
    {
        case kVK_Return:
            [self.searchField becomeFirstResponder];
        default:
            break;
    }
}

-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent*)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"Caught mouse event");
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    self.wordsFilteredTable.rowHeight = 37;

    NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];

    if( [tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"WordColumn"] )
    {
        NSString *word = [self.filterWordlist objectAtIndex:row];
        cellView.textField.stringValue = word;
        cellView.imageView.image = self.IMAGE_FILE;
        return cellView;
    }
    return cellView;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return [self.filterWordlist count];
}

- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj
{
    NSTextView* textView = [[obj userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSFieldEditor"];
    self.currentWord = [textView string];
    [self.filterWordlist removeAllObjects];
    for(NSString* word in self.wordlist) {
        if ([word hasPrefix:self.currentWord]) {
            [self.filterWordlist addObject:word];
        }
    }
    [self.wordsFilteredTable reloadData];

}

@end
```

And my AppView.m

```
#import "AppView.h"

@implementation AppView

- (void)setViewController:(NSViewController *)newController
{
    if (viewController)
    {
        [super setNextResponder:[viewController nextResponder]];
        [viewController setNextResponder:nil];
    }
    viewController = newController;
    if (newController)
    {
        [super setNextResponder: viewController];
        [viewController setNextResponder:[self nextResponder]];
    }
}

- (void)setNextResponder:(NSResponder *)newNextResponder
{
    if (viewController)
    {
        [viewController setNextResponder:newNextResponder];
        return;
    }
    [super setNextResponder:newNextResponder];
}

@end
```

Comment: Good question.   I speculate that something involved in loading the window and view has not completed at the time you call `becomeFirstResponder`.  `loadView` may not be where you want that.  But you may have few other choices, in which case you could leave it in loadView and try a `dispatch_async` to schedule the `becomeFirstResponder` after the view really loads.